# what does the vertical bar "|" mean in sentence-end?

Tags: regular-expressions

Reference to [12.1 The Regular Expression for sentence-end of Elisp introduction](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eintr.html#sentence_002dend)

It illustrate alternatives of sentence-end as

```
 \\($\\| \\|  \\)
        ^   ^^
       TAB  SPC
```

and explains:

> Two backslashes, ‘\\’, are required before the parentheses and
>   vertical bars: the first backslash quotes the following backslash in
>   Emacs; and the second indicates that the following character, the
>   parenthesis or the vertical bar, is special.

But what does the vertical bar "|" mean?

Comment: Please don't use tag `elisp`, except for questions about the nature of the language itself, as opposed to, for example, other Lisp dialects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertical bar lets you form an alternation, a regular expression which matches any one of several alternatives. Combined with the parentheses, this one matches either the end of the line, or a tab character, or two space characters. See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Regexps for details.